# When is a polynomial map is algebraic set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Is the image of every polynomial map $f:\mathbb{C}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$ an algebraic set?  If not, can we describe conditions on $f$ (and $m$, $n$) which determine when it is an algebraic set?

I am also curious to the answer to this question when the domain is taken to be some affine variety.

Comment: The general result is that the image of a map of varieties can only be guaranteed to be a constructible set (a finite union of locally closed sets). See "Chevalley's Theorem" for more details.

Comment: One obvious sufficient condition is to ask $f$ to be a closed immersion. This is equivalent to ask the map between coordinate rings $f^*:\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ to be surjective.

But this is not a necessary condition even if $f$ is injective, for example the map $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $f(z)=(z^2,z^3)$ has a closed image (it's image is the nodal cubic) but it is not a closed immersion (the map between algebras is not surjective).