# image of polynomial map is not an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am doing an exercise about algebraic geometry, where the exercise  tell us to provide example of the image of polynomial map $f:\mathbb{C}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ that is not an algebraic set. But I am thinking that the image of every polynomial is $\mathbb{C}$ thus every polynomial map is surjective. What have I misunderstand?

Comment: For the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932552/when-is-a-polynomial-map-is-algebraic-set). The (deleted) answer said: "Take $V=Z(1-xy)\subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ and consider the  map $\phi:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$. 


Image of $V$ under $\phi$ is, $\phi(V)=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, which is not an algebraic set of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$, $f(x,y) = (x,xy)$. Then the image is $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the non-zero part of the y-axis removed, which is not closed in the Zariski topology. Here the polynomial map is not surjective.

Comment: If y=1, isn't (x,x) ranged over all $\mathbb{C}^{2}$?Why it is not surjective?

Comment: @Ken.Wong $(x,x)$ doesn't range over $\mathbb{C}^2$, for example consider the point $(0,1)$.